# World of Tanks - Critical Error

Tags: wine

I have installed WoT on Ubuntu no problem, with the use of wine, however when I run the program I get a dialog box with a header that reads: "World of Tanks - Critical Error"
The dialog box reads: "An unhandled exception is occured
                       The application will be restarted"

My question is, Does any one know what causes such an error?
If so, How do I go about fixing this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are unskilled in terms of using wine, try play on linux. (https://www.playonlinux.com/en/app-1592-World_Of_Tanks.html) it will install winetricks and set your prefix, also it can install wine version of your choice on the run.... they even include wine-staging version, where many fixes are included (which official release doesnt have)

Download here: https://www.playonlinux.com/en/download.html

See here which packages you will have to install: https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=11544

Your error is 99% caused by missed additional package installed with winetricks

It should have World of Tanks on Games tab, so it will install everything for you! Just installer will be needed I guess...

Comment: I went to playonlinux and there was a button to install the program. However when I pushed it, Firefox came up with an error page that read "This Address Wasn't Understood". What I had to do was go to "Ubuntu Software Center" and download playonlinux from there. Then Install World of tanks on PlayonLinux. Thank you for this solution @Michal . One further question I have if you don't mind. Is there a read me or location where I can learn more about Wine and its functions? I would like to know how to use the program and how to run it effectivly.

Comment: I don't mind  ;), start here:  http://wiki.winehq.org/FrontPage